# Is there a way to dismiss an alertview automatically after some time?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm looking for a way, to automatically dismiss an alert view after some time or after a task is done.
Is there a possibility? (or another way to show a message for some time?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can call the [`-dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:` method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIAlertView_Class/UIAlertView/UIAlertView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIAlertView/dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:animated:) to dismiss the alert view.

To dismiss it automatically, create an NSInvocation and then use `-performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` to `-invoke` it.

Comment: yes this is good option... if you wanna leave the function. but if you don't wanna leave the function in execution then u can use NSRunLoop and loop until the task is done and then dismiss alert view. In such case, Macmade suggested NSTimer is okay.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView has a method called:

```
- ( void )dismissWithClickedButtonIndex: ( NSInteger )buttonIndex animated:( BOOL )animated
```

You can call it on your UIAlertView object to simulate a button press.
To dismiss it automatically after some time, you will need something like an NSTimer, to check if the alert view is still displayed, and in such a case, dismiss it.