# UIAlert View when no button press count 10seconds and do something

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview, nstimer

In my `UIAlertView` I have two buttons Yes, No. If I press `Yes` do something and if I press `No` cancel the `UIAlertView` so I can do this but my problem is that If I don't press any button it counts `10 seconds` and do something?

Is there any method?

Comment: you can use NStimer for cheking every 10 second is any Button our of all Button's state are Selected or not

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774960/is-there-a-way-to-dismiss-an-alertview-automatically-after-some-time

Comment: once check my answer it'l helps you.

Answer (score 1):

check this way it'l work. take timer of NSTimer class as a global variable.

> when you click on alert button at that time you must be `invalidate`
>   the timer.

in .h file declare like this

```
    NSTimer *timer;
    UIAlertView *myalert;

    myalert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"alert"message:@"hi" 
                                        delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"no"
                               otherButtonTitles:@"yes", nil];
    [myalert show];

   timer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:4.0 
                                           target:self selector:@selector(test) 
                                         userInfo:nil
                                          repeats:NO];

    -(void)test{
        [myalert dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
        //do somthing
    }
    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView 
        clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
        if(timer!=nil){
        [timer invalidate];
        timer=nil;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the `ActionMethod`? What calls `test:`?

Comment: @rmaddy :thank you mate i'have updated my answer.

Comment: The parameter to `test:` can't be a `UIAlertView`. It must be an `NSTimer`.

Comment: Also, you don't start the timer.

Comment: now this one working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hey try the following code

**ViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate> {

    UIAlertView *alertView;
    NSTimer *dismissAlertViewTimer;
}

@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
- (IBAction)btnShowAlertTouch:(id)sender {
    alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" 
                                           message:@"Your Message" delegate:self
                                 cancelButtonTitle:@"Yes"
                                 otherButtonTitles:@"No", nil];
    [alertView show];
   dismissAlertViewTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                                            target:self
                                                          selector:@selector(dismissAlertView)
                                                          userInfo:nil
                                                           repeats:NO];


}
// Function called on by timer to dismis the alertview
- (void)dismissAlertView {
    [alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:-1 animated:YES];
}

// Alert View Delegate
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex{
    if(dismissAlertViewTimer!=nil) {
        [dismissAlertViewTimer invalidate];
        dismissAlertViewTimer=nil;
    }
}
```

**[Sample Project Dropbox Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tojlfuzz7xy4g8x/SO-2774960.zip)**

Comment: You Guys Really Help me!Thank you to all of you :)

Comment: @user2396021 If you find **any** of the answers useful please **upvote it** and if answer is correct then 
please **accept it** this will help to remove the question from the list of **unanswered list of question**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if you use a "`NSTimer`" at the same time you create your "`UIAlertView`", you can have the timer method dismiss (or do whatever you want to do) your alert.

Answer (score 0):

Start the NSTimer when you show the alertview. and after 10 seconds write below code to dismiss your code. and `doSomethingbuttonIndex` is the same index on which you want to do something.

```
[alertView dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:doSomethingbuttonIndex animated:YES];
```

Comment: Problem here but with this method Yes and No button not working what I do?

Comment: @user2396021 So, If it is working for you. then i think you need to accept the answer.